# Оптимизация кода (ограничение значений)

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
        if($start < 0)
            $start = 0;
        else if($start > 1440)
            $start = 1440;
```

Есть ли какой либо стандартная операция, функция чтобы ее записать более красиво?

Comment: Эм, это же примитивные операции, зачем их заменять чем-то более сложным, только ради красоты?)

Comment: @lampa да, ради красоты и читаемости кода. Сомневаюсь вот еще, так же оставлять, или изменять )

Comment: @IVsevolod ну добавьте фигурные скобки, тогда точно будет красиво!)

Comment: you know what? [keep it simple, stupid](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF))

Comment: "keep it short and simple", хорошо ) думаю не буду трогать этот кусок кода )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На каждый случай специальных "стандартных операций, функций", разумеется, не напасешься. Поэтому, если это для вас такой критичный участок, можете сделать что-нибудь такое:

```
function someFunction($value, $min = 0, $max = 1440)
{
    //если есть аллергия к тернарным операторам, то можете заменить их на if
    return $value < $min ? $min :
           $value > $max ? $max : $value;

}
```

Возможно, php позволяет сделать еще проще

Comment: посмотрев на min max, пришла в голову еще одна идея по усложнению кода )

    $start = min( max( $start, 0), 1440);

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = $start < 0?0:($start > 1440?1440:$start);
```